# Why do I have to install the rails gem everytime I reboot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm, linux-mint

Everytime I reboot my Linux install I have to run the following 3 commands to be able to use

```
rails s
```

The 3 commands are:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
source /home/comfroels/.rvm/scripts/rvm
gem install rails
```

After I do this it works again... Do I need to do something globally?

Running Linux Mint 16

Comment: did you use `rvm use 1.9.3` and then `gem intall rails` then you will not  never do the same steps... as I see that your gems are installed in system not in rvm

Comment: You're not using RVM correctly if you have to `chmod /var/lib/gems`. Your question doesn't give us enough information. Is this a global multi-user installation of RVM or single-user? Do you have your ~/.bash_profile correctly set-up? *READ* the entire [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to check.